# IOS 8 keyboard how to swap between the decimal and numeric keyboard + shift key

Tags: ios, keyboard, decimal, numeric, shift

I am busy making an IOS 8 keyboard and I need some help.

I have made a basic keyboard and everything works fine but I have a bumps and I need some help to slove them. I wrote the code in swift(keep in mind I'm new to swift).

I need help with the following:

1. To swap the keyboard from decimal(the normal one with letters) to numeric(the number/symbol one) I wrote some code for it (It basically hides the keyboards respectively and shows them again) but I don't know how to make it run when I tap the "123" button.
2. When I type a key eg. "A" it prints out exactly how it appears on the keyboard how can I make it automatically lowercase and then implement a shift button to give me capital letters?

Some help to solve this would be much appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController
{

@IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!

var allButtons = [UIButton]()

override func updateViewConstraints()
{
    super.updateViewConstraints()

    // Add custom view sizing constraints here
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{

    //Normal Keyboard start
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let buttonTitles1 = ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"]
    let buttonTitles2 = ["A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"]
    let buttonTitles3 = ["⬆︎", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", "⬅︎"]
    let buttonTitles4 = ["123","","⎯", "Return"]

    //⚒

    var row1 = createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles1)
    var row2 = createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles2)
    var row3 = createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles3)
    var row4 = createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles4)

    self.view.addSubview(row1)
    self.view.addSubview(row2)
    self.view.addSubview(row3)
    self.view.addSubview(row4)

    row1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    row2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    row3.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    row4.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    addConstraintsToInputView(self.view, rowViews: [row1, row2, row3, row4])

    applyCurrentTheme()
    //Normal keyboard end







    //Change to numeric keyboard start

    let buttonsNum1FirstRow = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
    let buttonsNum2FirstRow = ["-", "/", ":", ";", "(", ")", "$", "&", "@", "\""]
    let buttonsNum3FirstRow = ["#+=", ".", ",", "?", "!", "'", "7", "⬅︎"]
    let buttonsNum4FirstRow = ["ABC","⎯","Return"]

    //define rows as class variable instead of function variable

    var Srow1:UIView!
    var Srow2:UIView!
    var Srow3:UIView!
    var Srow4:UIView!
    var Srow1Num:UIView!

    //Hide it like below:
    func didTapChangeToNumbersButton(sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        Srow1.hidden = true

        Srow1Num.hidden = false

    }
    //Change to numeric keyboard end


}

func createRowOfButtons(buttonTitles: [NSString]) -> UIView
{

    var buttons = [UIButton]()
    var keyboardRowView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50))

    for buttonTitle in buttonTitles
    {

        let button = createButtonWithTitle(buttonTitle)
        buttons.append(button)
        keyboardRowView.addSubview(button)
    }

    allButtons += buttons
    addIndividualButtonConstraints(buttons, mainView: keyboardRowView)

    return keyboardRowView
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
}

override func textWillChange(textInput: UITextInput)
{
    // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
}

override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput)
{
    // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

    var textColor: UIColor
    var proxy = self.textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
    if proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark
    {
        textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    else
    {
        textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}



func createButtonWithTitle(title: String) -> UIButton
{

    let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)
    button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
    button.sizeToFit()
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)
    button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: .Normal)

    button.addTarget(self, action: "didTapButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return button
}


func didTapButton(sender: AnyObject?)
{

    let button = sender as UIButton
    var proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy


    let capon = false;
    let capslast = false;
    let capslock = false;
    let spacelast = false;



    if let title = button.titleForState(.Normal)
    {


        switch title
        {

        case "" :
            self.advanceToNextInputMode()


        case "." :
            let capon = true
            proxy.insertText(".")
            let spacelast = false
            let capslast = false

     //Caps idea
     //this caps lock code is experimental and actually doesn't work, just an idea I was playing with
        case "⬆︎" :
            let capon = !capon
            if capslock
            {
                let capon = true
                let capslock = false
                let capslast = false
            }

            let capslast = true
       //Caps idea

        case "⬅︎" :
            proxy.deleteBackward()
            let spacelast = false
            let capslast = false

        case "Return" :
            proxy.insertText("\n")
            let spacelast = false
            let capslast = false

        case "⎯" :
            if spacelast
            {
                proxy.deleteBackward()
                proxy.insertText(". ")
                let spacelast = false
                let capon = true
            }

            else
            {
                proxy.insertText(" ")
                let spacelast = true
            }
            let capslast = false



        default :
            proxy.insertText(title)


        }
    }
}



func applyCurrentTheme()
{

    var theme = ClaptonTheme()

    theme.applyThemeToView(self.view)

    theme.applyThemeToKeys(allButtons)
}

func addIndividualButtonConstraints(buttons: [UIButton], mainView: UIView)
{

    for (index, button) in enumerate(buttons)
    {

        var topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1)

        var bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -1)

        var rightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!

        if index == buttons.count - 1
        {

            rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -1)

        }

        else
        {

            let nextButton = buttons[index+1]
            rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nextButton, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -1)
        }


        var leftConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!

        if index == 0 {

            leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1)

        }

        else
        {

            let prevtButton = buttons[index-1]
            leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: prevtButton, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1)

            let firstButton = buttons[0]
            var widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstButton, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: button, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

            widthConstraint.priority = 800
            mainView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
        }

        mainView.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstraint, rightConstraint, leftConstraint])
    }
}


func addConstraintsToInputView(inputView: UIView, rowViews: [UIView])
{

    for (index, rowView) in enumerate(rowViews) {
        var rightSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rowView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: inputView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -1)

        var leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rowView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: inputView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1)

        inputView.addConstraints([leftConstraint, rightSideConstraint])

        var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint

        if index == 0
        {
            topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rowView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: inputView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        }

        else
        {

            let prevRow = rowViews[index-1]
            topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rowView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: prevRow, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

            let firstRow = rowViews[0]
            var heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstRow, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: rowView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

            heightConstraint.priority = 800
            inputView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
        }
        inputView.addConstraint(topConstraint)

        var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint

        if index == rowViews.count - 1
        {
            bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rowView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: inputView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        }

        else
        {

            let nextRow = rowViews[index+1]
            bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rowView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nextRow, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        }

        inputView.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
    }

}
}
```